# Changing leftBarButtonItem position. It is far from the border

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a UIButton

```
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "draggerMore.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(crossBtnTapped))
```

and I set it as leftBarButtonItem

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = leftButton
```

This button the only one in navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems
The result is here:

[image]

I want the dagger to be close to the left side (as Restore button to the right).

I tried dif. ways from stack overflow such as  subview.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero in viewWillLayoutSubviews() 
but it didn't work for me. Maybe the problem is in back button which is invisible?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Try this:

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Comment: I understood your idea, but the functionality of my button is different than back btn. Back btn doesn't appear in my case because I don't have previous controllers